# MediaDevices Video Resize Event

Tags: javascript, resize, mediadevices

I'm using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to display a user video stream, and need to update the video size on a window resize event. Is there a way to update the width/height constraints on that stream after it's been initiated so that the video doesn't get stretched?

My init code looks like:

```
const stream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: false,
                video: {
                    facingMode: 'user',
                    width: window.innerWidth / 2,
                    height: window.innerHeight / 2,
                }
            })
            video.srcObject = stream
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign that stream to a Html Video Element then you can play with css and modify the size (of the Html Element) at your leisure.